# How to map file and rank to a square number in TSCP?

Tags: engines

How can I map file and rank numbers (0-7) to a square number in Tom Kerrigan's Simple Chess Program?

I know how to do the conversion from square number to rank and file, but not the other way around.

Comment: I may help, but a little more details will be helpful. What part of the code in TSCP you have issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversions from square to row and column are defined in defs.h as:

```
#define ROW(x) (x >> 3)
#define COL(x) (x & 7)
```

so you can apply the inverse to generate the square number:

```
(row << 3) | col
```